# Jquery function on specific window size

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-click-event

I'm trying to make a script only work when the user is in 1024 or less. It works somewhat okay, if the user don't resize the window. But when i fire the click event on lower than 1024 and then resize to lets say 1200 the toggle classes have been added and the animation trickers again.

Any suggestions?

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
    $("#primary-menu").click(function(){
        $(".main-navigation").removeClass("toggled");
        $(".cmn-toggle-switch").removeClass("active");
        $(".menu-item").toggleClass("animated").toggleClass("wow").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
    });

    $(".hamburger-menu-text").click(function(){
        $(".cmn-toggle-switch").toggleClass("active");
        $(".main-navigation").toggleClass("toggled");
        $(".menu-item").toggleClass("animated").toggleClass("wow").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
    });     
};
```

Comment: Consider to use `window.matchMedia()` method to avoid any bug https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia  That's said, it sounds like you would just need to use CSS media queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use if statement inside the click event

```
 $("#primary-menu").on('click',function(){
     if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        //..........
     }else{
        //..........
     }
});
```

Comment: I don't even think the `else` is needed here, from what the OP mentions if it's not within the window size requirements it should do nothing. Looks like everything would go in the `if`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I have to give the OP a little bit more of (code) .. May be he need it one a day .. may be :)

Comment: Thanks a lot:) works! And it works without the else statement. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check the window width on document ready and on window resize, and assign or remove the `click` listener:

```
var primaryFunc = function() {
    $(".main-navigation").removeClass("toggled");
    $(".cmn-toggle-switch").removeClass("active");
    $(".menu-item").toggleClass("animated").toggleClass("wow").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
}

var hamFunc = function() {
    $(".cmn-toggle-switch").toggleClass("active");
    $(".main-navigation").toggleClass("toggled");
    $(".menu-item").toggleClass("animated").toggleClass("wow").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
} 

var resetElements = function() {
   // Unbind the click event
   $("#primary-menu").off('click');
   $(".hamburger-menu-text").off('click');

   // remove assigned classes from elements
}

var checkWin = function() {
   var w = $(window).width();
   if (w <= 1024) {
       $("#primary-menu").on('click', function() {
          primaryFunc();
       });
       $(".hamburger-menu-text").on('click', function() {
          hamFunc();
       });
   } else {           
       resetElements();
   }
}
```

Execute `checkWin()` on dom ready and on window resize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWin();
})

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkWin();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input:) :) The solution above yours did work.